# Memoize + Biblatex + \cite causes compilation failure: \prepare@family@series@update ...get@series@value undefined

Tags: biblatex, fonts, errors, memoize

With updated TeX Live (2024-01-20), the following code produces an error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\cite{angenendt}
\end{document}
```

Initial compilation is fine, but compilation fails after `biber` generates the bibliography:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\prepare@family@series@update ...get@series@value 
                                                  \@empty \def \target@meta@...
l.51     \endentry
                  
?
```

I reported this as a [`memoize` bug](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/issues/9) because the error only occurs if `memoize` is loaded. Is there a way to workaround this, besides not using `memoize`? I'm really not sure how the error arises, given that the undefined control sequence seems to be from `latex.ltx`? (But the `...` isn't particularly helpful.)

Comment: memoize is doing `\csxdef {mmz@bbl@blub}{\pdf@mdfivesum {some arbitrary text from biblatex}}` and depending on the content of the arbitrary text this explodes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed on GitHub: https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/issues/9#issuecomment-1902549729.